# Jackson XML Deserialize single XML tag to Object

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I want to deserialize this xml tag:

```
<source>Test</source>
```

Into an Object (some java class).

I have the next class:

```
public class SomeXml{
  private String source;
}
```

And i'm doing the deserialization this way with Jackson XML:

```
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
SomeXml data = mapper.readValue("<source>Test</source>", SomeXml.class);
System.out.println(data);
```

But it gives me the next error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
> Unrecognized field "" (class com.test.SomeXml), not
> marked as ignorable (one known property: "source"])  at [Source:
> (StringReader); line: 1, column: 31] (through reference chain:
> com.test.SomeXml[""])

¿So how can i deserialize that single xml tag into an object/pojo?

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that XML it's a `String`, not an object (for Jackson).. instead you should surround it with another tag (that would be your object) containing that string (that would be the attribute)

```
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
SomeXml data = mapper.readValue("<myObj><source>Test</source></myObj>", SomeXml.class);
System.out.println(data);
```

to check what I've previously said, you can check that this code works fine:

```
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
String data = mapper.readValue("<source>Test</source>", String.class);
System.out.println(data);
```

Comment: The problem is that the "source" tag comes from an external, i can't modify how it comes. And doing it with the second way you commented, it gives me this error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token

Comment: @Stranger well, if what you are receiving is just that (and doesn't have like `<?xml ...>` at the beginning) you can just fo `"<obj>"+yourString+"</obj>"`

Comment: Yes, at the end i think that the best way of doing it is like this "<obj>"+yourString+"</obj>" since i can't change the format of the external data. Thank you very much for your help! :D

Comment: @Stranger it's the most naive... otherwise you might probably have to write your own ObjectMapper